# EPPlus in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, epplus

I want to use EPPlus for Excel import/export in a C++/CLI project.
When I try to access a single cell with the following code I get a compilation error:

```
ExcelPackage^ ep = gcnew ExcelPackage(gcnew System::IO::FileInfo("Test.xlsx"));
ExcelWorksheets^ sheets = ep->Workbook->Worksheets;
ExcelWorksheet^ sheet = sheets[1];
ExcelRange^ range = sheet->Cells[1, 1]; // this line causes C3252
```

Full error message:

```
error C3252: 'CellStore::Finalize': cannot reduce accessibility of a virtual method in a managed type
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'CellStore ' from assembly 'EPPlus, Version=4.5.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1'.
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'OfficeOpenXml::ExcelWorksheet ' from assembly 'EPPlus, Version=4.5.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1'.
```

Oddly enough this works in C#:

```
ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("Test.xlsx"));
ExcelWorksheets sheets = ep.Workbook.Worksheets;
ExcelWorksheet sheet = sheets[1];
ExcelRange range = sheet.Cells[1, 1]; // no error here
```

Is this something that ist just not supported by C++/CLI or ist there an error in my code or even in the EPPlus-library?

Comment: It is a [known problem](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/29).  As noted, editing CellStore.cs to make the CellStore class public and rebuilding the library fixes it.  But, realistically, if you want support from the library maintainers then you'd better move this code into a C# class library.

Comment: I was afraid that this would the only possibility. I'll probably follow this approach then. Thank you for your answer.